# NativeScript 2.0 Custom Components and CSS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm having an issue with NativeScript 2.0 CSS and custom components. There seems to be a giant gap in my knowledge and I'm missing something vital that is non-obvious.

Take an empty NS 2.0 app created with

```
$ tns create test --ng
```

Delete the contents of ***app.css*** (to prevent side effects).

Change ***app.component.ts***:

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    template: `
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Label text="Label in first StackLayout"></Label>
        <StackLayout orientation="vertical" 
                     style="width: 80%;background-color: red;">
            <Label text="Label in second StackLayout"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
    `,

})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Pretty basic stuff. Produces the following *expected* result:

[image: Expected result]

---

Let's try to convert that inner StackLayout into a reusable component.

***custom.component.ts***

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "Custom",
    template: `
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" 
                 style="width: 80%;background-color: red;">
        <Label text="Label in second StackLayout"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    `,

})
export class CustomComponent {}
```

Change the ***app.component.ts***

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {CustomComponent} from "./custom.component"

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    directives: [CustomComponent],
    template: `
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
        <Label text="Label in first StackLayout"></Label>
        <Custom></Custom>
    </StackLayout>
    `,

})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Now the output looks like this:

[image]

The background color is applied but the width is not.

I even tried:

```
<Custom style="width: 80%;"></Custom>  /* Does this even make sense? */
```

to no avail.

I realize percentages are [experimental](http://docs.nativescript.org/ui/layouts#percentage-support) but suspect the error is in my code rather than NativeScript.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I reviewed your code in the given code snippet and found that it could be NativeScript issue. At the moment changing the width of the `StackLayout` in your `CustomView`  using inline style will be working only on Android. To change the width of your CustomView using % for both platform at the moment you should setup this property in your `css` file and bind `cssClass` property.

**custom.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "Custom",
    template: `
    <StackLayout orientation="vertical" 
                 [cssClass]="styleView" style="background-color: red;">
        <Label text="Label in second StackLayout"></Label>
    </StackLayout>
    `,

})
export class CustomComponent {

      public styleView="customViewStyle";

}
```

**app.css**

```
.customViewStyle{
    width:80%;
}
```

Comment: I  just checked Android. You're right; works fine. Unfortunately I can't get iOS to change even with CSS style (which still works in Android). Thanks for the insight

Comment: I am sorry for the delay in replying. I made a little research and edited my answer above. Possible fix for this issue could be to bind `cssClass` property and than to set class name. I tested it on both `iOS` and `Android` and it should work normally on both platforms.